# 【SOLVED】LLVM DILocation: extract information from metadata

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

I wanna get value and `861` from a return instruction, for example `ret i32 %3, !dbg !861` and it's metadata `!861 = !DILocation(line: 8, column: 5, scope: !857)`. But it didn't work.

> version of clang and llvm is 13.0.0

```cpp
for (auto &B : F) {
  for (auto &I : B) { 
    // get metadata
    if (auto *inst = dyn_cast<ReturnInst>(&I)) {
      // ret i32 %3, !dbg !861
      // !861 = !DILocation(line: 8, column: 5, scope: !857)

      errs() << "!!!return inst: " << *inst << "\n";

      DILocation *DILoc = inst->getDebugLoc().get();
      errs() << "   " << DILoc << "."<< "\n";

      Type *instTy = inst->getType();
      errs() << "   " << *instTy << "."<< "\n";
      
      Value* val = dyn_cast<Value>(inst);
      errs() << "   val name: " << val->getName().str() << ".\n";

      if (auto constant_int = dyn_cast<ConstantInt>(val)) {
        int number = constant_int->getSExtValue();
        errs() << "   val number: " << number << ".\n";
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

and the result:

```
!!!return inst:   ret i32 %3
   0x0.
   void.
   val name: .
```

I nearly got nothing! Problems:

##### 1. **`DILocation` return 0x0, why?** I wanna get information of `!861 = !DILocation(line: 8, column: 5, scope: !857)`

Actually, now I find my true problem.

- I used clang++ -O0 -g -S -emit-llvm test1.cpp -o test.ll to get .ll file. So it generate the metadata.
- When I used clang++, I didn’t use -O0 -g. So it didn’t generate the metadata.
  So the function LLVM: llvm::DebugLoc didn’t work.
  And now, after I added the two arguments, the code I wrote works!

##### 2. **return type is `void`, why?** I thought it should be `ret`.

> Nick Lewycky said: The return instruction, locally to the current function, is **void**, it does not produce a value that subsequent instructions in the same function can consume. > **%a = add i32 %b, %c** makes sense, but **%a = ret i32 %b** does not.
> A ret instruction itself always has void type, no matter what type the function is returning.
> If you want the type of the returned value you could ask **inst->getReturnValue()->getType()**.
> Thanks **Nick Lewycky**!

Comment: Look at the source of e.g. [llvm-dis](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-dis.html) for an example of how to do it.

Comment: "return type is `void`, why? I thought it should be `ret`." The return instruction, locally to the current function, is void, it does not produce a value that subsequent instructions in the same function can consume. `%a = add i32 %b, %c` makes sense, but `%a = ret i32 %b` does not. A `ret` instruction itself always has `void` type, no matter what type the function is returning. If you want the type of the returned value you could ask `inst->getReturnValue()->getType()`.